# Node JS - Замена условного оператора полиморфизмом

Tags: javascript, node.js

Доброго времени суток! 
Чем в Node JS грамотно заменить длинный условный оператор, в моём случае это switch-case? Есть ли смысл вводить классы либо использовать замену алгоритма (чтобы заранее изменить поведение системы)? Вопрос возник в связи с тем, что только недавно в JS пришли классы, но как правило их не любят использовать, так как это лишь синтаксический сахар.

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса ... как класс поможет избавиться от switch? Классы - сахар для прототипов, а не магия вне Хогвартса улучшающая любой код (даже многострочные свичи). Кто не любит использовать классы? Классы классные ...

Comment: большие switch заменяются на таблицы вызовов, т.е. на массив или объект содержащий имена функций (или сами функции), которые надо вызвать. И то при условии, что создание отдельных функций и их вызов оправданы. А уж для введения классов надо 7 раз подумать, из за одного участка со switch их все таки вводить как то перебор. Классы обычно полностью меняют подход к алгоритму и в целом по программе и решение о рациональности их применения принимается исходя из нужд всей программы в целом.

Comment: И ни в коем случае нельзя говорить "все switch длиннее N case зло и их надо заменять на шаблон X", в каждом конкретном случае надо рассматривать целесообразность того или иного подхода. Гвозди конечно микроскопами вполе себе забиваются, так же как и воробьи отлично сбиваются из пушек, но вот стоит ли оно того ...